Complete data sequence with NA for missing months in R?
I have a data.frame like below where I don't have record for winter months i.e. January, February, November and December. I want to compelete the Date sequence such that my first Date start with 2001-01-01 and ends on 2003-12-31 where NA is provided for the Missing winter months. Any help would be appreciate.
DF <-data.frame(Date = seq(as.Date("2001-01-01"), to = as.Date("2003-12-31"), by = "day"),
                        Ob = runif(1095,1,5), Sim = runif(1095,1,5)) %>% 
                      filter(between(month(Date),3,10))


Do you use {zoo}? There is a common procedure to populate time series. create a synthetic one and merge. Why are you using the tidyverse? merge should be enough (and is probably faster).

Maybe you can try left_join like below
data.frame(
  Date = seq(as.Date("2001-01-01"), to = as.Date("2003-12-31"), by = "day")
) %>%
  left_join(DF)


Fantastic! exactly what i needed. Thanks

We can use complete
library(tidyr)

DF %>%
  complete(Date = seq(as.Date("2001-01-01"), as.Date("2003-12-31"), by = "day"))

Note
The input in reproducible form (adding set.seed and library calls):
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

set.seed(123)

DF <-data.frame(
    Date = seq(as.Date("2001-01-01"), to = as.Date("2003-12-31"), by = "day"),
    Ob = runif(1095,1,5), 
    Sim = runif(1095,1,5)) %>% 
  filter(between(month(Date),3,10))

